# Antiseptic role of kerosene

Tags: everyday-chemistry, chemical-biology

When I was kid and got a huge cut on my finger, I remember my grandmother putting lots of kerosene on my wound, as there was no health facility around.

I want to confirm. Do chemists agree on the antiseptic role of kerosene, or was grandma just using useless remedy?

Comment: All medical advice is off topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a note to anyone considering it as an antiseptic agent, it is toxic and probably absorbs through the skin.
Any compound that causes a change in osmotic pressure within a pathogen may kill it through plasmolysis, depending on how much of the compound is soluble in water.  There may be other mechanisms by which a hydrocarbon poisons pathogens like the interruption of metabolic pathways.
Anyhow petroleum distillates are dangerous to apply to the skin and nobody should ever do it on purpose.